# jsconcpp linker problems

Tags: c++, curl, jsoncpp

I am trying to run the program detailed [here](http://blog-of-darius.blogspot.com/2011/07/geocoding-with-c-and-google-geocoding.html). The code requires the cURL and JSON libraries, and I've been following the direction [here](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/README.txt)

I'm having trouble running the program - when I compile I get unresolved external symbol linker errors for both cURL and JSON, so I seem to have done something wrong.

I'm a complete novice when it comes to programming, so any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please add the errors to your question, and also how you build the application.

Comment: Please add linker error message to your question it's impossible to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in my [post](http://blog-of-darius.blogspot.com/2011/07/geocoding-with-c-and-google-geocoding.html) I specified custom path to include and library directories for compiler as follow:

```
g++ -g -Wall -Ilibs/include -Llibs/lib -o prog prog.cpp CURLWrapper.cpp -lcurl -ljson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt
```

replace I[libs/include] -L[libs/lib] paths with directories where are your put libraries (cURL and JSON).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `jsoncpp` library header address and compiler flags to your compiler. for example for g++ you should do like this:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/jsoncpp/ -ljsoncpp yourCode.cpp
```